# How to split HDF5 compund datatype in C++

Tags: c++, scientific-computing, hdf5

I have an HDF5 file with a compound type (int, double, double). Currently I am reading it in a single operation by storing its result in an array of structures, following [the example in the documentation](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/compound_8cpp-example.html).

However I would prefer instead to save each of the three parts in a different array, so I would like to provide 3 pointers, (int*, double*, double*) and read the data directly in the 3 arrays without copying data.

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible directly.

You can easily copy your array of structures into three arrays in a loop:

```
int a[n];
double b[n], c[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    a[i] = s[i].a;
    b[i] = s[i].b;
    c[i] = s[i].c;
}
```

assuming `s` is an array of `struct { int a; double b; double c; }` of (constant) size `n`, but I have a feeling that you are looking for a direct HDF5 way…

Clearly, an hyperslab won't work since I believe that a compound type is atomic. Anyway a compound type implies that the data is stored *compound* in the file so it is probably more efficient to read it that way. The only limitation with the solution I gave you is memory if your array is *really* large. On a modern computer that should be ok though ;)

Comment: thanks simon, I do not want to copy the data, I am more memory limited than IO limited, so at this point I prefer to access the file 3 times as I am currently doing and read one field at a time...my array can be few TB.

Comment: in my understanding the answer is that it is not possible as @Simon says.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a single field in a compound type. Suppose your dataset is opened as `dset` with three fields `"a","b","c"`, of `LENGTH` elements, then

```
int a[LENGTH];
double b[LENGTH], c[LENGTH];    

CompType atype(sizeof(int));
atype.insertMember("a", 0, PredType::NATIVE_INT);
dset.read(a, atype);

CompType btype(sizeof(double));
btype.insertMember("b", 0, PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
dset.read(b, btype);

CompType ctype(sizeof(double));
ctype.insertMember("c", 0, PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);
dset.read(c, ctype);
```

This should be doing what you asked for. Maybe you are already doing this by "reading the file three times"?